# Mongodb: Indexing field of sub-document that can be either text or array

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of documents representing messages. Each message has multiple fields that change from message to message. They are stored in a "fields" array of sub-documents.

Each element in this array contains the label and value of a field. 
Some fields may contain long lists of strings (IP addresses, URLs, etc.) - each string appears in a new line within that field. Lists can be thousands of lines long.
For that purpose, each element also stores a "type" - type 1 represents a standard text, while type 2 represents a list. When there's a type 2 field, the "value" in the sub-document is an array of the list.

It looks something like this:

```
"fields" : [
{
    "type" : 1,
    "label" : "Observed on",
    "value" : "01/09/2016"
},
{
    "type" : 1,
    "label" : "Indicator of",
    "value" : "Malware"
},
{
    "type" : 2,
    "label" : "Relevant IP addresses",
    "value" : [
        "10.0.0.0",
        "190.15.55.21",
        "11.132.33.55",
        "109.0.15.3"
    ]
}
```

]

I want all fields values to be searchable and indexed, whether these values are in a standard string or in an array within "value".

Would setting up a standard index on "fields.value" index both type 1 and type 2 content? do I need to set up two indexes?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a new index, `mongodb` will automatically switch to `Multikey index` if it stumbles across an array in a document on the indexed field.
Which means that simply:

```
collection.createIndex( { "fields.value": 1 } )
```

should work just fine.

see: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/index-multikey/

Comment: Thanks! I looked into the documentation but must have missed it.